# CodeIgniter and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

CodeIgniter and AJAX Problem

```
my base_url=http://localhowt/project1/

site_url=http://localhowt/project1/index.php
```

I have a controller name `methods.php` and within that a method is `insert_data()`.

From one of my view page i tried to call the controller methods.php using `$.ajax` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/project1/index.php/methods/insert_data",
            dataType: "json",success:function(data){
                alert("success");
            }
        });  
    });
});
</script>
```

This AJAX code doesn't redirect to controller page. But I did not get any response from this ajax code.

Comment: Any error messages you could supply? Perhaps from firebug, access-logs or php-logs.

Comment: You are not getting any response because you do not have a code defined for error handling. You need to add a `error` handler. See the [jQuery AJAX page for details](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Does your function `echo` anything?

Comment: is your base_url() and site_url() just typos, or are those the actual strings you get from base_url()? If yes, you have urls wrong ( locahowt / localhost ), in other case, please edit your question ^^

Comment: I have answered similar question, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12758973/1403159

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `site_url()` function to properly generate the `url` parameter. Secondly, you should do what Silviu G said. And thirdly you should do what nerdklers said :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all.. I got my answer from u and can understand my mistake. Some days i were too bg with another job so i could not get in touch with u..Thanks again MR.Silviu,Mr. Tom and others